# django template show dynamic python code call result

Tags: django

I can get a dynamic Python function call result in the interpreter.

```
def test1():
    ''' i assume it will cost 2 seconds '''
    #code here
    print 'test1 success...'

def test2():
    ''' i assume it will cost 2 seconds '''
    #code here
    print 'test2 success...'

def test3():
    ''' i assume it will cost 2 seconds '''
    #code here
    print 'test3 success...'

def run():
    test1()
    test2()
    test3()
```

when i execute the 'run' function,i can get content on the interpreter screen after first 2 seconds.

```
test1 success
```

then 4 seconds later content on the interpreter screen:

```
test1 success...
test2 success...
```

then 6 seconds later content(the final) on the interpreter screen:

```
test1 success...
test2 success...
test3 success...
```

After each function finished,i can get its result or status show on the the interpreter screen.

But how can I make this dynamically happen within a Django template? Is it different from a variable value change? Can Javascript and AJAX fix it?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Exactly what do you want to achieve, and what does that code snippet have to do with it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I suppose the OP simply wants to dynamically update a variable in a Django template. This variable probably changes its value in a prespecified interval.

Comment: @Peter Stahl Agree with your opinion. I just want to show the content or one variable value in django template dynamically from api or function's callback which would change constantly. tks

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have added some more information about the question. Hope i have made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically update a variable in a template, you need JavaScript and AJAX for that, yes. Otherwise, you would have to reload the entire template in a regular interval which is probably not what you want (and which is not recommended).

The best way to work with AJAX calls is to use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).